# How to animate sprites on the tileMap in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, tiles

I created an animated sprite, but I am not understanding how to add the animated sprite on the tilemap. My animated sprite(player) walks without tiles, but when I add the animated sprite on tile that does not work(the walking).

Comment: what do you mean by tile map?

Comment: tile Map is a combination of spritesheet. spritesheet divided into tiles.

Comment: Thanx , but i dont know how to add code here. If ur comfortable then give me ur mail id send my code

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to start with a tutorial or sample project when you need to get multiple things working. I started with [KnightFight](https://github.com/lozarcher/KnightFight) project for my own tile map game. This project has a very good skeleton for animating characters on tile map.